# Trying to create a schema in IBM Watson IoT gives me 'Internal Error' - why..?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson

I'm trying to follow this guide: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/GA_information_management/ga_im_index_scenario.html#scenario

But as soon as I hit "Manage Schemas" in the device type section I get an "Internal Error", saying I should contact the Admin... I'm not able to create schemas. What's going wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Tom

Comment: Do you know what region you created your Watson IoT service in? It would be US-south, eu-go or eu-de?

Comment: If you are not sure which region then post your Watson iot org id (should be in the url when you are logged into the iot dashboard) and I can look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. If you are simply trying to retrieve the raw events that have been published by your device, then you need to use a URL for the form:

```
/api/v0002/device/types/{deviceType}/devices/{deviceId}/events/{eventName}
```

This is documented in the Watson IoT Platform [API reference](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002/info-mgmt.html#!/Last_Event_Cache/get_device_types_deviceType_devices_deviceId_events_eventName).

It is worth noting that, if this is all you are trying to achieve, you do not need to follow the guide that you referenced.  It is possible to retrieve the raw events using the REST API simply by defining the Device Type and registering your device.

The guide that you referenced describes the Data Management capabilities of the Watson IoT Platform.  These capabilities allow you to process the raw events in order to generate/compute state for the device.  This is more involved than simply retrieving the raw events because you need to configure schemas for the events and the state and then define the mappings that tell the platform how to compute the properties on the state when an event is received.  The computed state for a device is a different resource and needs to be retrieved using a different URL:

```
GET /api/v0002/device/types/{typeId}/devices/{deviceId}/state/{logicalInterfaceId}
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002/state-mgmt.html#!/Devices/get_device_types_typeId_devices_deviceId_state_logicalInterfaceId)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing, but that *Manage Schemas* section of the UI is not related to the feature you're looking at as part of the guide you referred to.

The guide you're looking at outlines how to configure event schemas and logical interface schemas for a Device Type using REST API calls.  If you wish to create this configuration using the web UI, this is possible too but you need to get to the *Interfaces* section from the *Device Types* view: [see this image](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s733/sh/7fafea54-c925-4182-834f-794884de0298/a86cc082750d91b6/res/e4f2b0e4-fc23-468d-b384-3acc91a44185.png?resizeSmall&width=832&alpha=)

In this case, I clicked on the `Humidity Sensor` Device Type and then, in the expanded view, clicked on the `Interface` tab.  From there you can use the *Simple* or *Advanced* flows to create the configuration.

Comment: [this link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s733/sh/7fafea54-c925-4182-834f-794884de0298/a86cc082750d91b6) shows a series of screen-grabs in which I create a simple config for this device type

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: I followed your advice, thanks again. But I'm still not sure how to fetch devices's data from an external website using an http request. The above mentioned guide is not really applicable when you can't use the "manage schemas" section. I created a PI and an LI, created a API Key and token. I can't find a guide telling me how to use this set of data to request i.e. temperature values via php script. Btw, I'm new to his stuff, as you might have guessed. :) Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Once you have the specified, and _activated_ the Device Type configuration, you can retrieve the state associated with a specific Device using [this api](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002/state-mgmt.html#!/Devices/get_device_types_typeId_devices_deviceId_state_logicalInterfaceId)

TLDR; 
It's a `GET` against: `{yourOrgId}.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/device/types/{typeId}/devices/{deviceId}/state/{logicalInterfaceId}`

Comment: This will return a JSON object such as:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2016-09-16T17:32:10.000Z",
  "updated": "2016-09-16T15:26:12.000Z",
  "state": {
    "temperature": 38.4
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I assume, I have to put the API key and token in the http header for authorization?

Comment: That's correct, you need an `Authorization` header which has the following value structure:

`Basic <base64 encoded apikey:token>`

For example, if you had **apikey** `username` and **token** `password`, the `Authorization` header would have the value:

`Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`

Where `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` is `username:password` as a Base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because the component that provides the function on that page (Real time insights) is not present in the eu-de region. The page should not be present but for some reason is.

If you are planning on following that [guide](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/GA_information_management/ga_im_index_scenario.html#scenario) then this is a different part of the UI from the “manage schemas” page, and is located under the “interfaces” section in “device types”. The function defined in that guide is available in eu-de.